# Setting mean value for Poisson subsampling

Tags: poisson-distribution

I'm running a machine learning algorithm in `federated settings`  where participants collaboratively build a model by participating in the training rounds.

At each training round, I need to sample a fixed number of participants, say `100` out of a total population of `500` to participate in the training.

The selection of participants should be based on `poisson subsampling` such that each participants is drawn with subsampling probability of `100/500`.

I perform `poisson subsampling` with randomly selected `lambda` from the range `[0,500]`, and keep subsampling with random `lambda` values until the `100` participants are drawn.

A small python snippet below

```
sampled_ids = []
participants_size = 100
population_size = 500


while len(sampled_ids) < participants_size:

  lambda_value = np.random.random_integers(low=0, high=population_size, size=1) 

  subsampling = np.random.poisson(lam=lambda_value, size=participants_size)

  for i in range(len(subsampling)):
           if len(sampled_ids) < participants_size:
                    sampled_ids.append(instance)
```

**Is there any better strategy for setting the `lambda` other than random selection so the `100` participants are drawn with probability `p = participants_size/population_size` ?**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos
Thanks for the info, question updated.